# Apply expanding function over whole df - numba and alternatives?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to apply an expanding window operation on the whole df - not columnwise.
The method=table requires numba engine. But I always get an error when calling it (see below)

I would also appreciate it, if anyone could point out another solution to my problem (i.e. I don't necessarily want to use numba).

```
S = pd.Series([i / 100.0 for i in range(1, 11)])
d_from = pd.concat([S, S], axis=1)
# In a df expanding operates column or rowwise
d_from.expanding(axis=0).apply(sum, raw=True)
d_from.expanding(axis=1).apply(sum, raw=True)
# can use table arg and numba to operate on whole df?
d_from.expanding(axis=1, method="table").apply(sum, raw=True, engine="numba")  # throws exception
```

The last line produces : "numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of builtin `sum()` use `np.sum()`:

```py
S = pd.Series([i / 100.0 for i in range(1, 11)])
d_from = pd.concat([S, S], axis=1)

d_from.expanding(axis=1, method="table").apply(
    np.sum, raw=True, engine="numba"
)
```